# Show a tree structure in dropdown html

Tags: javascript, html, tree, dropdown

I am making my code changes below and would like to show my tree structure in the form of a dropdown

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/kc9fehyz/

[image]

```
var vDOM = document.createDocumentFragment(); //Create a Document Fragment to store your Virtual DOM
function formCategoryTrees(object,par) { //Use the parent node as a parameter to create hierarchy
   var ul = document.createElement('ul');
   _.each(object,function(objectValues ){       
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var leafCategoryId = objectValues["id"];
        var leafCategoryName =  objectValues["name"]; 
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(leafCategoryName + " " + leafCategoryId));

        if(objectValues["children"]) {      
                formCategoryTrees(objectValues["children"],li);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);

    })    
    par.appendChild(ul);  //Append to the parent node after each iteration
}
formCategoryTrees(object.records,vDOM);
document.body.appendChild(vDOM); //Append your Virtual DOM to your page
```

Comment: So , what's the problem?

Comment: https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Comment: i want to show this in a dropdown rather than a jstree

Comment: @vini How did you end up implementing this?

Comment: @ShervinShahrdar I used jstree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jsTree plugin of jQuery.

[Here](https://www.jstree.com/demo/) a demo.

You have to write something like:

```
$('#jstree_demo').jstree({
  "core" : {
    "animation" : 0,
    "check_callback" : true,
    "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
    'data' : {
      'url' : function (node) {
        return node.id === '#' ?
          'ajax_demo_roots.json' : 'ajax_demo_children.json';
      },
      'data' : function (node) {
        return { 'id' : node.id };
      }
    }
  },
  "types" : {
    "#" : {
      "max_children" : 1,
      "max_depth" : 4,
      "valid_children" : ["root"]
    },
    "root" : {
      "icon" : "/static/3.2.1/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
      "valid_children" : ["default"]
    },
    "default" : {
      "valid_children" : ["default","file"]
    },
    "file" : {
      "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
      "valid_children" : []
    }
  },
  "plugins" : [
    "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
    "state", "types", "wholerow"
  ]
});
```

**If give us more details, I can help you better.**